# Scheduling kube-dns on dedicated node pool

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kube-dns

I have a cluster running on GCP that currently consists entirely of preemtible nodes. We're experiencing issues where kube-dns becomes unavailable (presumably because a node has been preempted). We'd like to improve the resilience of DNS by moving `kube-dns` pods to more stable nodes.

Is it possible to schedule system cluster critical pods like `kube-dns` (or all pods in the `kube-system` namespace) on a node pool of only non-preemptible nodes? I'm wary of using affinity or anti-affinity or taints, since these pods are auto-created at cluster bootstrapping and any changes made could be clobbered by a Kubernetes version upgrade. Is there a way do do this that will persist across upgrades?

Answer (score 6):

The solution was to use taints and tolerations in conjunction with node affinity. We created a second node pool, and added a taint to the preemptible pool.

Terraform config:

```
resource "google_container_node_pool" "preemptible_worker_pool" {
  node_config {
    ...
    preemptible     = true

    labels {
      preemptible = "true"
      dedicated   = "preemptible-worker-pool"
    }

    taint {
      key    = "dedicated"
      value  = "preemptible-worker-pool"
      effect = "NO_SCHEDULE"
    }
  }
}
```

We then used a `toleration` and `nodeAffinity` to allow our existing workloads to run on the tainted node pool, effectively forcing the cluster-critical pods to run on the untainted (non-preemtible) node pool.

Kubernetes config:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      # The affinity + tolerations sections together allow and enforce that the workers are
      # run on dedicated nodes tainted with "dedicated=preemptible-worker-pool:NoSchedule".
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: dedicated
                operator: In
                values:
                - preemptible-worker-pool
      tolerations:
      - key: dedicated
        operator: "Equal"
        value: preemptible-worker-pool
        effect: "NoSchedule"
```

Comment: How does that solve the problem of scheduling pods like kube-dns though?

Comment: We tainted the preemtible node pool, forcing kube-dns to run on a second standard pool of untainted nodes. Any pods that do not have the toleration to run on the preemptible pool (including any cluster critical services) will fall back to running on the standard pool.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, so it is not important that kube-dns be on all nodes? It seemed to me that k8s was trying to schedule it on the tainted node and so wasn't succeeding (even though there is non-tainted nodes available where kube-dns is already running).

Comment: I can’t speak to your specific architecture and use case, but DNS failures have dropped to nearly zero since adopting the architecture above. Another option (perhaps in addition) could be to install a DNS caching service like dnsmasq.